# Writing generic script to upload data from file into database table

Tags: python, c, database, shell

Please consider this scenario :

I have different tables in database say table1,table2,table3.....

Now, for each of these tables I have data coming into flat files which will be inserted into corresponding table.

I want to write a generic script which will read the first line of the flat file and determine which table it should be inserted into by matching the data types in flat file with the schemas of the tables present.

Assumption : All the tables taken into account will have different schemas.

Please suggest whether this is feasible, if yes please guide on how this can be acheived.

Comment: It's feasible, but decidedly tricky.  You'll need an appropriate description of each table available to the script.  You'll need a modestly complex tool to classify input fields (123 looks remarkably like '123' - strings vs integers vs decimals vs ...).  And you'll only be heuristically correct in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this generic code:

```
import os
import glob
import MySQLdb

path = '/path/to/directory/containing/flatfiles'
conn_mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd="root",db="dbname")
cursor_mysql = conn_mysql.cursor()
table_to_use = ""
for filename in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.txt') ):
    print "Reading file: " + filename
    currentfile = open(filename, 'r')
    numcols = currentfile[0].split()
    if numcols is 10:
        table_to_use = "tbl1"
    elif numcols is 7:
        table_to_use = "tbl2"
    # So on and so forth
    for line in currentfile[1:]:
        insert_data_to_database(line, table_to_use)
        #use the above function to insert data based on the table_to_use
```